# Offline password manager for Windows Phone

Tags: offline, password-manager, windows-phone

Is there an offline password manager for Windows Phone?

It has to store all of my passwords in my phone, because I do not trust the cloud.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cannot say these work, because I haven't tested them. But based on my searches, here are a couple of options.

When you said

> I do not trust the Cloud

I thought of Keepass, probably one of the best Open Source offline password managers out there. It functions by storing the data in an encrypted file. There are three Windows Phone apps for Keepass, as follows:

- [7Pass](http://7pass.wordpress.com/): Says it works with Windows Phone 7 and 8.1
- [WinPass](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/apps/winpass/9nblggh5z10k): Says it works with Windows Phone 7 and 8.1
- [WinKee](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/apps/winkee/9wzdncrdcghc): Says it works with Windows Phone 8.1

I note that you used the Windows 10 tag, does this mean that you are using the Windows Phone 10 beta? If so, I'm pretty sure all of the above should work on it.

More Info: [Keepass Site](http://keepass.info/index.html) and [Keepass Downloads Page](http://keepass.info/download.html)